# Change EaselJS canvas width without scaling content

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, easeljs

I've got a zoom button in my application which scales the children of a container using scaleX on each child.

But this makes the content extend beyond the canvas width. So I would need to additionally change the canvas width, but that seems to generally scale the canvas and the content - if I use...

```
$('canvas').width($('canvas').width() * 2);
```

...which I don't want. I basically just want to set a new width.

Any advice for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The JQuery `width` method sets the width using CSS, which will stretch the canvas instead of setting its pixel dimensions. From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/width/):

> Set the CSS width of each element in the set of matched elements.

Instead you can access the canvas element and set it directly, or use the `attr` method.

```
// Direct
var elem = $("canvas").get(0);
elem.width = someValue;
elem.height = someOtherValue;

// Or using attr
$("canvas").attr("width", someValue);
```

Hope that helps!